# ASPNET 5.0 minimal permissions for app pool account

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, permissions, asp.net5

I've started hardening the physical folder configurations of our existing ASP.NET Core/ASP.NET 5.0 apps and I was wondering if anyone can point me to some official documentation from MS on this topic.

After some tests, I've noticed that the app pool account has to have read and execute permissions on the folder where the site is hosted. A simple read won't cut it.

After some trial and error, these are the minimum permissions under which a simple ASP.NET 5.0 can run:

[image: Advanced permissions]

Can anyone explain why all these permissions are required? For instance, why is "read extended attributes" required?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/default-permissions-user-rights#inetpubwwwroot

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, i was interested in getting the minimum required permissions (and understanding why execute is required for the top folder)...

Comment: 1. That default folder’s setup is the minimal. You might definitely change that, but only replacing some with equivalent. 2. No documentation is going to explain why a certain thing like execute is required, and IIS is not open sourced. So all you can do is to accept the fact.

Comment: Hello again. Well, I've managed to get away with the permissions I've shown above. I've managed to get it working, but I'm curious...For instance, I'd really love to know why it's required to have "read extended attributes" in order for it to work (why not a simple read...).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the application pool permission to read or execute the folder where the application is located, you can follow the steps below.

Right click the site and click Edit Permissions...

[image]

Select Security, Edit, Add. Type in application pool's name.
[image]

Click OK. Then check the permission for application pool.
[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. What I'd really like to get is some official information from MS on what's needed for hosting a .net core/.net 5 core app. For instance, I've managed to get it to run by giving the app pool account read, read&execute and list folder contents to the physical folder. But why do I need to grant it read&execute? I thought that read should be enough

Comment: I found some documents about permission but not permission between IIS Application pool and folder. [File and folder permissions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb727008(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)